# winHQ on Ubuntu 22.04 issues: "304 Not Modified"

Tags: wine, wget

I need to install wineHQ on Ubuntu 22.04 and later on GrapeJuice. [Here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) the lines of code I need for such installation.

My problem is that, despite I have an almost pristine system, attending the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9tWv-jOgUo&t=313s), in  2' 24'' MY system response is

```
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources

--2023-01-04 12:01:42--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
Resolving dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)... 151.101.242.217
Connecting to dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)|151.101.242.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources’ not modified on server. Omitting download.
```

which is not the some as in the video.
Particularly, I can see that while in the tutorial video I read something like "awayting response... 200 ok", my system says: "awaiting response... 304 Not Modified", which suggested me that things are not working.

Could you explain me what does or should do this code in my system, please?
Furthermore, why my response is not the some as in the video (does a previous wine 6.0 installation could be the reason for that?).
Finally, what should I do in order to fix it and keep going with my installation, please?

Comment: I have this neat [script](https://github.com/RishonDev/get-wine-latest.sh) which i used for personal purposes. clone the repository, run `sudo chmod +x *.sh`, run the uninstaller script, and finally, run the installer script according to your version.

Comment: Still I don't know what's going on. But it works perfectly!

Comment: Did you check that the file existed?